# Realizar 2 funciones distintas en un evento onclick de javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un enlace que funciona como botón y que al pulsar aparecerá desde fuera de la página un `div` que se posicionará encima de lo que hay en el `html` en esa posición. Al volver al pulsar el mismo botón, quiero que vuelva a salir fuera de la pantalla del mismo modo que entró. Este es mi código js:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    var work=document.getElementById("work2");
    var flechaWork=document.getElementById('flecha_work');
    flechaWork.addEventListener("click",function(){
        if(flechaWork.style.left=="50%"){
            work.style.left="-60%";
            work.style.transition = "all 1.3s";
        }
        else{
            work.style.left="50%";
            work.style.transition = "all 1.3s";
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Y cual es el error?. Se muestra el div?

Comment: Podes utilizar Jquery?

Comment: @ArielOctavioD'Alfeo jquery es javascript pero no todo javascript es jquery. Apoyaría tu respuesta en jquery pero sería muy bueno también explicarlo con JavaScript "puro y duro".

Comment: se que jquery es una librería de js, pero te pregunto porque muchos no la quieren utilizar, usan solo JS. la respuesta con jquery seria con el evento toggle() como te respondieron mas abajo

Comment: El código de Raúl está bien y sólo necesita un cambio para funcionar. El problema es que en la comparación se está comprobando la posición de `flecha_work` cuando se debería estar comprobando la posición de `work2`. Una vez hecho ese cambio, ya se alternan las acciones correctamente (como muestro [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/3725/250)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código está bien... o casi. Es más simple que algunas de las soluciones planteadas y lo único que tienes que hacer es corregir un error muy simple. Si te fijas, en la comparación para determinar en qué posición está el elemento `#work2` **¡en lugar de comprobar la posición de `#work2`, compruebas la posición de `#flecha_work`!**:

```
    // aquí deberías estar comprobando work2
    if(flechaWork.style.left=="50%"){
        work.style.left="-60%";
        work.style.transition = "all 1.3s";
    }
    else{
        work.style.left="50%";
        work.style.transition = "all 1.3s";
    }
```

**Como luego en el código lo que cambias es el estilo de `#work2` la condición siempre va a irse por el `else` y por eso no ves que se alternen las acciones**.

La solución: cambia la condición para que se compruebe la posición de `#work2`:

```
    if(work2.style.left=="50%"){
```

Y entonces las acciones ya se alternan sin problemas:

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    var flechaWork=document.getElementById('flecha_work');
    var work=document.getElementById("work2");
    flechaWork.addEventListener("click",function(){
        if(work.style.left=="50%"){
            work.style.left="-60%";
            work.style.transition = "all 1.3s";
        }
        else{
            work.style.left="50%";
            work.style.transition = "all 1.3s";
        }
    })
})
```

```css
#work2 {
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:-60%;
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
  color:white;
  background:black;
}
```

```html
<button id="flecha_work">Pulsame, soy flecha_work</button>
<div id="work2">
Soy Work2
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, mi código siempre pensé que estaba bien planteado, pero tantas horas delante de la pantalla y pasa esto a veces, que fallas en lo más tonto y no lo tienes en cuenta.

Comment: @RaúlMorenoPovedano nos pasa a todos, a mí el primero :)

Answer (score 2):

Si pero en realidad es más fácil que la función que escribiste.

```
<button onClick="ejecutar_dos_funciones()" >Ejecutar</button>

<script>

function ejecutar_dos_funciones()
{
  funcion_uno();
  funcion_dos();
}

function funcion_uno()
{
 alert("funcion uno");
}

function funcion_dos()
{
 alert("funcion dos");
}

</script>
```

Comment: Esto no es lo que quiere OP. No es cuestión de ejecutar dos funciones una detrás de la otra, sino alternar entre la primera y la segunda

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo quieres hacer una especie de `flip flop` entre las dos acciones,
de ser asi podrias adjuntar una funcion u otra al evento agregandolo o removiendolo.

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    var work=document.getElementById("work2");

    var flechaWork=document.getElementById('flecha_work');
    flechaWork.addEventListener("click",flecha1);
});

function flecha1(){
    work.style.left="-60%";
    work.style.transition = "all 1.3s";

    var flechaWork=document.getElementById('flecha_work');
    flechaWork.removeEventListener("click", flecha1);
    flechaWork.addEventListener("click",flecha2);
}

function flecha2(){
    work.style.left="50%";
    work.style.transition = "all 1.3s";

    var flechaWork=document.getElementById('flecha_work');
    flechaWork.removeEventListener("click", flecha2);
    flechaWork.addEventListener("click",flecha1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quizas te sirva un evento toggle()

```
<div id="target">
  Click aquí
</div>

$( "#target" ).toggle(function() {
    alert( "Probando acción 1" );
 }, function() {
    alert( "Probando acción 2" );
 });
```

Obviamente hay que cambiar los alerts por las funciones que desees.
Ahora, un poco más actual sería de esta forma.

```
$( "#target" ).toggle( display );

if ( display === true ) {
  $( "#target" ).show();
} else if ( display === false ) {
  $( "#target" ).hide();
}
```

Puedes ver la documentación y ejemplos aquí: https://api.jquery.com/toggle/
Espero te ayude en algo.
Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer un campo hidden que tenga como valor inicial 0 y luego en la función que llamas con el onclick puedes comprobar ese valor. Si está a cero realizas una de las acciones y ones el valor del campo hidden a 1. Y si está a 1 haces la otra opción y pones el valor del campo hidden a 0. Así podrás alternarlo